# Wrap pairs of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

If you have the following code:

```
<div class="parent">

    <div class="1a"></div>
    <div class="1b"></div>

    <div class="2a"></div>
    <div class="2b"></div>

    <div class="3a"></div>
    <div class="3b"></div>


</div>
```

Is there an efficient/easy way to wrap a new div around each a + b so it finishes looking like this:

```
<div class="parent">

   <div class="new-1">        
       <div class="1a"></div>
       <div class="1b"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="new-2">        
       <div class="2a"></div>
       <div class="2b"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="new-3">        
       <div class="3a"></div>
       <div class="3b"></div>
   </div>


</div>
```

For example can I say something like:

wrap every two divs inside .parent with `<div class="new-(incremental variable)"></div>` (the new wrapping divs need to have a unique class)

Comment: Are the original divs generated? The best thing to do would be to generate the surrounding divs at that point. If they're static, you should statically code the surrounding divs as well. You should also consider using less specific class names on the children elements. E.g. `class="a"` and `class="b"` are reusable - there should not be a need to have a number in front of them as they do not need to be unique. If you need each group styled differently, you can select more specifically using parent nodes. E.g. `new-3 a` and `new-3 b`, but even those parent nodes are rather specific classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('.parent > div:odd').each(function(i){
    $(this)
       .prev()
       .addBack()
       .wrapAll($('<div/>',{'class': 'new-' + (i+1)}));
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wMBTj/)**

Get the odd ones selected i.e 1, 3, 5 etc based on index(0 based); Iterate the **[odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)** ones get the **[prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)** element relative to the odd(which needs to be paired), use <strike>**[andSelf](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)**</strike> **[addBack](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)** to select that too and then use wrapAll on the pair.

if you want to ignore first x of them then do this:

```
$('.parent > div:gt(' + (x-1) + '):odd').each(function(i){
    $(this)
         .prev()
         .addBack()
         .wrapAll($('<div/>',{'class': 'new-' + (i+1)}));
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hc9fV/)**

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Thanks so much. (Remove other question, solved it and works perfecto)

Comment: Thanks very much once again :)

Comment: @user2413333 Just noticed the other question was also urs.. :)

Comment: It should be noted that [andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) if you are using jQuery 1.8 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

You can literally use jQueries Wrap function. Take a look here!

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you wish to achieve with the new wrapper divs but nth-child in CSS might be useful. Try something like this:

```
div.parent div {width:50%;}
div.parent div:nth-child(odd) {clear:both; float:left;}
div.parent div:nth-child(even) {float:right;}
```

...which will give you pairs of divs side by side.